# How to return status code in JSON format iin Rest Api?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am using Restful web services(new to this topic).I am able to insert an Todo Object in database and retrieve the newly inserted Todo Object.But I am getting the response back as newly inserted object when I am using :

```
@PostMapping("/jpa/users/{username}/todos")
    public ResponseEntity<Todo> createTodo(
            @PathVariable String username, @RequestBody Todo todo){


        todo.setUsername(username);
        Todo createdTodo = todoJpaRepository.save(todo);


        return new ResponseEntity<Todo>(createdTodo, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I am getting response of 200 as:

```
 {
    "id": 8,
    "username": "aaa",
    "description": "p",
    "targetDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "done": false
    }
```

I want my JSON format to be like below when I get the response :

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "username": "aaa",
    "description": "p",
    "targetDate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "status": 200,
     "message" : "Created Successfully"
    }
```

Is it possible to get in this way?I searched for other websites ,but didn't got the solution.

Comment: Do not use database entities directly as return object in an API.

Comment: what should i use then?

Comment: In opinion it makes no sense to duplicate the return code.

Comment: The return object should be a pojo.

Comment: can u give me the best solution as I am new to this topic?

Comment: The best answer you already have from @Jens: There is no sense to send HTTP status code in the response body. Your server sends already the status code 200 and browser receives it.

Comment: As i am using AJAX,yes then how can I compare whether data is inserted succesffuly or not in my front side? Suppose if i can get status as 200 in json then i can compare response.status=200 print("successfully saved") or i can print("Error") using javascript .I think comparing from status will be easy

Comment: Well if you really want to return a status code in the Json, you'll need to wrap your entity in a message that contains both the entity and the status code. But I think that you should stay with the HTTP code, it's better that way and more standard